# Why a null result is freezing the script and how to avoid it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, null, freeze

When I use the below code:

```
if(string.match(/td>0/g).length == 8) {
    /*Do something*/
}
```

and no `/td>0/` are matched, it returns a `null` result that prevents the script below from executing.

I would like to know why the code is freezing, and how to avoid it and find a solution or an alternative to `.match()` ?

Comment: or `if ( (string.match(/td>0/g) || []).length === 8)`, also, the console can be opened with F12

Comment: Thks for all your answers and so quick response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(More Recommended):

```
var matching=string.match(/td>0/g);
if( matching != null && matching.length === 8) {
    /*Do something*/
}
```

Use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: This answer could be improved so you are not running the regular expression check twice. But if you like code to run twice, this is the answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a `null` check first -

```
if(string.match(/td>0/g) != null && string.match(/td>0/g).length == 8) {
    /*Do something*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to make a null check before checking the length. I would do either do the match first and than check

```
var result = string.match(/td>0/g);
if (result && result.length) {}
```

or use an or to catch the null

```
if( (string.match(/td>0/g)||"").length ) {}
```